# Excel VBA Grab Ancestor value from Relational Data

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dictionary

I can't seem to figure out how this would work in excel VBA

I have this relational data in excel like so:

[image]

Hierarchially / treeview, data looks like this:

[image]

The End result of the data should look like this (After using excel VBA script) where

- columns A and B is relational Data
- column E is input values for lookup
- Column F is result ancestor value

[image]

My script thus far looks like this:

```
Public Sub DictionaryExamples()

    Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ActiveSheet

    Dim exampleValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aKey As String
    Dim aValue As String
    Dim exampleDict As Object

    'Load values into a variant array
    exampleValues = Range("A1:B15").Value

    'Instantiate a dictionary
    Set exampleDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'Read all keys and values, and add them to the dictionary

    For i = 1 To UBound(exampleValues)
        aKey = CStr(exampleValues(i, 1))
        aValue = CStr(exampleValues(i, 2))
        exampleDict.Add aKey, aValue
    Next i

    'After Dictionary setup, use input values E to output Ancestor F
    Dim curCell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim temp As Variant

    LastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row

    'Loop through all values in parent to find ancestor
    For Each curCell In sht.Range("E1:E" & LastRow).Cells
        temp = curCell

        'Search Dictionary until no matches are found, that is ancestor
        Do
            If exampleDict.Exists(temp) Then
                temp = exampleDict(temp)
            Else
                'Print ancestor
                curCell(, 2).Value = temp
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

    Next



End Sub
```

Result so far: (not getting correct output values)

[image]

Essentially I am using a dictionary (A= key, B=value) to use as a lookup for (E=input) and then output (F=results)

I loop through multiple times until I find a key that has no pair, and use the latest working key value as the ancestor

The "root" words in the data is unncessary I just put it there for clarification, it could a null value I just wanted to clarify which input levels are already top level ancestor values

Comment: what's your recommendation on how to go about solving this problem? Besides using dictionaries. Maybe a Vlookup wrapped in a loop? Or just resort to python?

Comment: I guess that I was mistaken about this not being a hierarchy.  I suppose that it is a 2 dimensional hierarchy.  In any case, I am about to post the corrected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether your child node's parent is a root element or is a leaf  (child node) itself before continuing your loop.  Otherwise, you will always be writing the value of the parent node, which is "Root", and never the parent's name (key).

[image]
    Option Explicit

```
Public Sub DictionaryExamples()

    Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Dim exampleValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aKey As String, aValue As String
    Dim exampleDict As Object
    Dim curCell As Range

    'Load values into a variant array
    exampleValues = Range("A2:B15").Value

    'Instantiate a dictionary
    Set exampleDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'Read all keys and values, and add them to the dictionary

    For i = 1 To UBound(exampleValues)
        aKey = CStr(exampleValues(i, 1))
        aValue = CStr(exampleValues(i, 2))
        exampleDict.Add aKey, aValue
    Next i

    'After Dictionary setup, use input values E to output Ancestor F


    With sht
        'Loop through all values in parent to find ancestor
        For Each curCell In .Range("E2", .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
            aKey = curCell
            'If the
            If Not exampleDict.Exists(exampleDict(aKey)) Then
                'If the node is a parent node print it's value
                'To avoid confusion I'd have used: curCell(, 2).Value = "Parent Node"
                curCell(, 2).Value = exampleDict(aKey)
            Else
                'Search Dictionary until no matches are found, that is ancestor
                Do
                    If exampleDict.Exists(aKey) Then
                        'Here we test if this child node's parent is a root node
                        If Not exampleDict.Exists(exampleDict(aKey)) Then
                            'The child node's parent is a root node
                            curCell(, 2).Value = aKey
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            'The child node's parent is also a leaf so continue
                            aKey = exampleDict(aKey)
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: some reason when i run 1000 input cells with my own relational data it doesn't populate anything in the "F" ancestor field. Dictionary is 100 cells long. Any idea on why this is?

Comment: If you email me the data I'll test it.  tommy70458@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (Not my original solution, received help elsewhere)

```
Option Explicit

Private Const LOOP_LIMIT As Integer = 100

Public Sub LineageDemo()

    Dim dict As Object
    Dim inputValues As Variant
    Dim outputValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Read relations into dictionary
    Set dict = BuildDictionaryOfRelations(Range("A2:A140"), Range("B2:B140"))

    'Read input values into variant array
    inputValues = Range("E2:E1465").Value

    'Write output
    ReDim outputValues(1 To UBound(inputValues), 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(inputValues)
        outputValues(i, 1) = TraceAncestor(CStr(inputValues(i, 1)), dict, "Root")
    Next i

    Range("F2:F1465").Value = outputValues

End Sub

Private Function BuildDictionaryOfRelations(childRange As Range, parentRange As Range) As Object

    Dim childValues As Variant
    Dim parentValues As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim aChild As String
    Dim aParent As String
    Dim dict As Object

    If childRange.Columns.Count <> 1 Or parentRange.Columns.Count <> 1 _
        Or childRange.Rows.Count <> parentRange.Rows.Count Then _
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, Description:="Bad/inconsistent category ranges"

    'Load values into variant arrays
    childValues = childRange.Value
    parentValues = parentRange.Value

    'Instantiate a dictionary
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    'Populate the dictionary

    For i = 1 To UBound(childValues)
        aChild = CStr(childValues(i, 1))
        aParent = CStr(parentValues(i, 1))
        If aChild = "pizza-oven" Then Stop
        dict.Add aChild, aParent
    Next i

    Set BuildDictionaryOfRelations = dict

End Function

Private Function TraceAncestor(aChild As String, relationDict As Object, rootString As String) As String

    Dim aParent As String
    Dim i As Integer

    If Not (relationDict.exists(aChild)) Then
        TraceAncestor = "ERROR: " & aChild & " does not appear in the CategoryName column"
        Exit Function
    End If

    'If aChild is a root, return root
    If relationDict.Item(aChild) = rootString Then
        TraceAncestor = rootString
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Trace from child to parent to parent to parent... to find ultimate ancestor
    For i = 1 To LOOP_LIMIT
        If Not (relationDict.exists(aChild)) Then
            TraceAncestor = "ERROR: " & aChild & " does not appear in the CategoryName column"
            Exit Function
        End If
        aParent = relationDict.Item(aChild)
        If aParent = rootString Then Exit For
        aChild = aParent
    Next i

    If i > LOOP_LIMIT Then
        TraceAncestor = "ERROR: Ancestor could not be found for " & aChild & " in " & LOOP_LIMIT & " iterations"
        Exit Function
    End If

    TraceAncestor = aChild

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I only had about 1000 to 2000 cells or so, so I ended up using Jerry's Cascading tree formula here

https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/text-functions/cascading-tree

```
Option Explicit

Sub TreeStructure()
'JBeaucaire  3/6/2010, 10/25/2011
'Create a flow tree from a two-column accountability table
Dim LR As Long, NR As Long, i As Long, Rws As Long
Dim TopRng As Range, TopR As Range, cell As Range
Dim wsTree As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find top level value(s)
Set wsData = Sheets("Input")
  'create a unique list of column A values in column M
    wsData.Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
         CopyToRange:=wsData.Range("M1"), Unique:=True

  'Find the ONE value in column M that reports to no one, the person at the top
    wsData.Range("N2", wsData.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
        .Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(C2,RC13)=0,1,"""")"
    Set TopRng = wsData.Columns("N:N").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1).Offset(0, -1)
  'last row of persons listed in data table
    LR = wsData.Range("A" & wsData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Setup table
    Set wsTree = Sheets("LEVEL STRUCTURE")
    With wsTree
        .Cells.Clear    'clear prior output
        NR = 3          'next row to start entering names

'Parse each run from the top level
    For Each TopR In TopRng         'loop through each unique column A name
        .Range("B" & NR) = TopR
        Set cell = .Cells(NR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

        Do Until cell.Column = 1
          'filter data to show current leader only
            wsData.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell
        'see how many rows this person has in the table
            LR = wsData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If LR > 1 Then
              'count how many people report to this person
                Rws = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, wsData.Range("B:B")) - 1
              'insert that many blank rows below their name and insert the names
                cell.Offset(1, 1).Resize(Rws).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                wsData.Range("B2:B" & LR).Copy cell.Offset(1, 1)
              'add a left border if this is the start of a new "group"
                If .Cells(.Rows.Count, cell.Column + 1).End(xlUp).Address _
                    <> cell.Offset(1, 1).Address Then _
                       .Range(cell.Offset(1, 1), cell.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown)) _
                          .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
            End If

            NR = NR + 1     'increment to the next row to enter the next top leader name
            Set cell = .Cells(NR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        Loop
    Next TopR

  'find the last used column
    i = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
  'format the used data range
    With Union(.Range(.[B1], .Cells(1, i)), .Range("B:BB").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23))
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 53
    .Range("B1").Value = "LEVEL 1"
    .Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B1", .Cells(1, i)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With

wsData.AutoFilterMode = False
wsData.Range("M:N").ClearContents
wsTree.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This did 95% of the work I needed to do, the rest I just used excel formulas (no VBA needed afterwards)

#### steps to get ancestor data from start:

I did following procedure:

0: Have data in a relational data setup

1: Cleaned out any duplicate data *conditional formatting for duplicates*

2: Run Jerry's Excel VBA Macro. Results below

```
Col A | ColB  | ColC  | ColD  | ColE  | ColF  |
      | Lvl1  | Lvl2  | Lvl3  | Lvl4  | Lvl5  |

      | AAA   |       |       |       |       |
      |       | BBB   |       |       |       |
      |       | EEE   |       |       |       |
      |       | FFF   |       |       |       |       
      | CCC   |       |       |       |       |
      |       | GGG   |       |       |       |       
      |       |       | III   |       |       |
      |       |       |       | JJJ   |       |
      |       |       |       |       | KKK   |
      | DDD   |       |       |       |       |
      |       | HHH   |       |       |       |
```

3: Populate the the top level excel via copy+pasting through excel *(I only had 3 parent top level categories, so it took 2 minutes)*

```
Col A | ColB  | ColC  | ColD  | ColE  | ColF  |
      | Lvl1  | Lvl2  | Lvl3  | Lvl4  | Lvl5  |

      | AAA   |       |       |       |       |
      | AAA   | BBB   |       |       |       |
      | AAA   | EEE   |       |       |       |
      | AAA   | FFF   |       |       |       |       
      | CCC   |       |       |       |       |
      | CCC   | GGG   |       |       |       |       
      | CCC   |       | III   |       |       |
      | CCC   |       |       | JJJ   |       |
      | CCC   |       |       |       | KKK   |
      | DDD   |       |       |       |       |
      | DDD   | HHH   |       |       |       |
```

4: Then use a helper column in column A, via this formula

`=IF(B19<>"", B19,
IF(C19<>"",C19,
IF(D19<>"",D19,
IF(F19<>"",F19))))`

where C, D,E,F are subcategories levels stemming from the parent (Column B). This searches values in column C for input, if its not there, then column D, then E, then F and copies whatever it finds first.

```
Col A | ColB  | ColC  | ColD  | ColE  | ColF  |
      | Lvl1  | Lvl2  | Lvl3  | Lvl4  | Lvl5  |

      | AAA   |       |       |       |       |
  BBB | AAA   | BBB   |       |       |       |
  EEE | AAA   | EEE   |       |       |       |
  FFF | AAA   | FFF   |       |       |       |       
      | CCC   |       |       |       |       |
  GGG | CCC   | GGG   |       |       |       |       
  III | CCC   |       | III   |       |       |
  JJJ | CCC   |       |       | JJJ   |       |
  KKK | CCC   |       |       |       | KKK   |
      | DDD   |       |       |       |       |
  HHH | DDD   | HHH   |       |       |       |
```

5: Then use an index / match function now that all data is normalized (on columns A and B) using my original input values as the lookup

6: Clean up any data afterwards manually

Step 3 can be easily macro'd for larger sets of data, just traverse that column and paste until it finds the next value down.